# A View.environmentObject(_:) may be missing as an ancestor of this view - but not always…

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm getting this error in production and can't find a way to reproduce it.

> Fatal error > No ObservableObject of type PurchaseManager found. A
> View.environmentObject(_:) for PurchaseManager may be missing as an
> ancestor of this view. > PurchaseManager > SwiftUI

The crash comes from this view:

```
struct PaywallView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var purchaseManager: PurchaseManager
    var body: some View {
        // Call to purchaseManager causing the crash
    }
}
```

And this view is instantiated in subviews of the MainView

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let purchasesManager = PurchaseManager.shared
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(purchasesManager)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or, when called from a UIKit controller, from this controler:

```
final class PaywallHostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    init() {
        super.init(rootView:
                    AnyView(
                        PaywallView()
                            .environmentObject(PurchaseManager.shared)
                    )
        )
    }
    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I tested all the use cases that trigger the PaywallView to show up, and I never got a crash.

FWIW, the PurchaseManager looks like this:

```
public class PurchaseManager: ObservableObject {   
    static let shared       = PurchaseManager()
    init() {
        setupRevenueCat()
        fetchOfferings()
        refreshPurchaserInfo()
    }
}
```

Why would the ObservableObject go missing? In which circumstances?

Comment: Maybe because of `private`. or maybe u should do this: `.environmentObject(PurchaseManager.shared)`

Comment: Please add code of how did you implement `PurchaseManager.shared`

Comment: @Asperi why? what are you looking for?

Comment: @Asperi Done. I added the implementation.

Comment: maybe some functions (such as `fetchOfferings`) in your  `PurchaseManager` `init` are asynchronous. This could be the reason your problem is intermittent.

Comment: @workingdog Interesting. Care to expand a bit and turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your problem is intermittent, is probably because the `PurchaseManager` `init()`
could finish
before all the data is setup properly, due to the "delays" of the
async functions in `init()`. So sometimes the data will be available
when the View wants it, and sometimes it will not be there and crash your app.

You could try the following approach that includes @atultw advice of using
StateObject.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var purchaseManager = PurchaseManager() // <-- here
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .onAppear {
                    purchaseManager.startMeUp()    // <-- here
                }
                .environmentObject(purchaseManager)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var purchaseManager: PurchaseManager
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
        List {
            ForEach(purchaseManager.offerings, id: \.self) { offer in
                Text(offer)
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PurchaseManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var offerings: [String] = []
    
    // -- here --
    func startMeUp() {
        // setupRevenueCat()
        fetchOfferings()
        // refreshPurchaserInfo()
    }
    
    func fetchOfferings() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
            self.offerings = ["offer 1","offer 2","offer 3","offer 4"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1/ how is that data not set properly since there's a default value for the offerings? and 2/ why the deadline?
Fwiw, the singleton is a temporary compromise to simplify things as the app is rewritten from UIKit to SwiftUI. While I don't like it either, I don't seem to see any clear reason why it's relevant to this crash.

Comment: it's hard to answer your questions, when we don't have a reproducible example code 
of your problem, all I can do is speculate. Yes there's a default value for the offerings,
but imagine you are looping using indices, and then due to the async functions, the indices change,
it may create problems. Could you show what is causing the crash in `PaywallView`, 
 which I guess may be `MainView`. The best would be to show an example code that shows your issue.
 Note that in my simple tests, the singleton was not a major issue for me.

Comment: the `deadline` is just a simple simulation of an async function that takes a bit of time to complete, since you don't show what is in `fetchOfferings()`

Comment: Thanks @workingdod. I don't have more to work with, but you gave me plenty. I think there's a problem with the way fetchOfferings/refreshPurchaserInfo work together. Plus I spotted another issue with environmentObjects, and also this https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swiftui-environment-when-presenting-views/.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use the singleton pattern here (`.shared`), `EnvironmentObject` is meant to be a replacement for it. You should instantiate PurchasesManager in MyApp.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var purchasesManager = PurchaseManager() 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(purchasesManager)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

without state object compiles fine but needed if you want child views to update automatically.

Doing those things with a dummy PurchasesManager runs fine for me.

Comment: Not the answer I needed, but I agree that it should be a singleton, so that's still helpful & worth an upvote. Thanks